# How to recursively "put" folders in RSE synchronise

Tags: eclipse, synchronization

I've just upgraded Eclipse to Kepler and thought I'd try the built-in RSE as an alternative to the JCraft SFTP plugin for remote sync over SSH. I've exported my project with Review/Synchronise ticked and in the Synchronise panel I can see the files I want to export.

If I right-click a file I get a "Put" option to send the file but if I right-click a folder the option is not there.

How to I "put" a folder? There's no way in hell I'm going to do each file individually.

Comment: Why don't you try to do that with another IDE or a separate program and use Eclipse for effective development?

Comment: Because it's convenient to do it all in one place and because RSE is supposed to handle this. My workflow is mostly lots of tiny updates being pushed/pulled to/from a live webserver so things like Git don't work well and even if I rsync from a console I still have to refresh Eclipse when local files change. It's annoying and JCraft SFTP handles it pretty well but has its own issues (it sucks at recursive deletes for example).

Comment: " Git don't work well " I doubt that.

Comment: I'm not adding a commit message every time I change one character of a CSS file. Git is not suitable. I also have to work with others who wont/cant use Git. Git works for programmers who change a lot of things at once and test locally. I can't test locally.

Comment: You can type any commit message, also you can write a small app to generate everything you need on commit (like adding a commit message) if you want. Also, in your situation git is not "not working". You are lazy to write commit messages and some people are not going to use git. So you do not want to use it, as you do not think it is feasible for your situation. But the statement saying that git does not work is simply untrue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try [PTP Synchronized project](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PTP/sync-projects) instead of RSE. It is mostly used for C/C++/Fortran development, but it can be used for any project for which you want to edit remote files. The feedback we got from PTP users is that the Synchronized projects work usually better (e.g. faster) than the RSE ones. In the future it is planned that you can use synchronized projects without having to install all of PTP.

Comment: Sounds like perfect alternative. I wont have time to test it before the bounty expires so I'll accept it on faith.